# overflow:scroll div with position:absolute element inside

Tags: css, scroll, css-position, absolute

I have a table inside a overflow:scroll container, there are some buttons inside table, when someone click them, they show a contextual/tooltip (position:absolute layer) text.

When I scroll to the right and click the button, it moves outside to the right ignoring scroll:

[image]

Making container position relative solves the position problem, but its appear inside the container not showing the menu:

[image]

I need help to get the following desired behavior:

[image]

This is the snippet:

```css
.container{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
  position:relative; /* removing this solves the problem, but .contextual moves to the original position */
}
.board{
  width:400px;
}
.contextual{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
    <table class=board>
      <tr><td colspan=2>This board size (200) is bigger than its container size (100).</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>this is a button with a contextual element</td>
        <td>
          <input type=button value="click me" onclick="$('.contextual').show();" />
          <div class=contextual>This is a contextual help text.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the contextual div outside of the overflowing div and position it according to the mouse position.

```js
showContext = function() {
    var e = window.event;

    var posX = e.clientX;
    var posY = e.clientY;
    var context = document.getElementById("contextual")
    context.style.top = posY + "px";
    context.style.left = posX + "px";
    context.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.container{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
  position:relative; /* removing this solves the problem, but .contextual moves to the original position */
  z-index:1;
}
.board{
  width:400px;
}
#contextual{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:grey;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <table class="board">
      <tr><td colspan=2>This board size (200) is bigger than its container size (100).</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>this is a button with a contextual element</td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="javascript:showContext();" />
          
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="contextual">This is a contextual help text.</div>
```

Comment: Long time ago but any suggestion on how to make this work for hover?

Comment: @vojislav how about change onclick to onmouseover?

Comment: @vojislav I would do as suggested in the comment above. And perhaps use addEventListener instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Answer (score 5):

### For people who have this issue, but setting to mouse position won't help

If you have the same problem as me, that the parent container is set to `overflow: scroll` and the parent's child element is cut off despite `position: absolute` - do the following

**Usecase for instance, building an dropdown**

- Set the element to `position: fixed`
- Get the parent element's Viewport positions
- Set the positions `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` values to the viewport values

*you can use the same code as the code snippet from @jfeferman*

Comment: In my case, only `position: fixed` was enough. No more...

Answer (score -5):

You can use `overflow: auto`. This will show the scrollbars only when necessary. Also, you can remove the `z-index: 2` from `.contextual`.